# How do i save state of toggle checkbox on or off in user interface

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Newbie to front-end world...I have a use case specifically in which i need to save toggle state on or off depending on user choice.

1. If a user has previously selected toggle ON then i need to make sure that toggle is on for that particular user next time he or she visits the page.
2. if a user has previously selected toggle OFF then i need ot make sure that toggle is off for that particular user next time her or she visits the page.

Below is my html implementation

```
<div class="toggle-checkbox">
    <label class="showLabel" for="show">Toggle on or off :</label>
    <label class="toggle">
      <input class="toggle-input" id="togBtn" type="checkbox" (click)="validate()" />
      <span class="toggle-label" data-off="OFF" data-on="ON"></span>
      <span class="toggle-handle"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the external typescript file i am trying to save the state like this -

```
validate(){
    var input = document.getElementById('togBtn') as HTMLInputElement;
    
    if (input.checked) {
          localStorage.setItem('togBtn', 'true');
      
        } else {
          localStorage.setItem('togBtn', 'false');
        }

}
```

tried this in typescript file but everytime i tried to re-visit the page with same request information then the toggle information is not saved for that user. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the checkbox model from local storage and set the checkbox model like this:

```
 const togBtn = localStorage.getItem("togBtn");
 var input = document.getElementById('togBtn')
  input.checked = JSON.parse(togBtn );
```